# jQuery load multiple html files in one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

How do i load multiple html files and putting them into a specified html element?

I tried with no changes:

```
$('#asd').load('file.html,pippo.html');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could get multiple items and add them to the element.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false }); //if order matters
$.get("file.htm", '', function (data) { $("#result").append(data); });
$.get("pippo.htm", '', function (data) { $("#result").append(data); });
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: true });  //if order matters
```

Comment: `data1` and `data2` are deferred objects, not text/html. Your code as posted will append the string `[object Object][object Object]` to `.result`

Comment: You're right @Kevin B.  I've modified the post to include the callback functions in the get() calls.

Comment: I hate to rain on this parade, but if getting wwa.htm takes way longer than getting wb0tpl.htm then you could easily have them append out of order (or if they take similar time, in varying order each time you try it). Kevin B's solution does not have that problem.

Comment: Yeah to let this code work any time, you should do the second $.get in the callback of the first $.get. Which becomes quite messy with lots of $.get's

Comment: I don't get why u made a function appendToResult(). Why didn't u just use $("#result").append(); ?

Comment: @gl3nn, I changed to include the append call.  Also, I added the wrapping with "async" in case order matters.

Comment: great! I like your async : false method. Wouldn't have thought of that.

Comment: @gl3nn Using `async:false` locks the browser during the requests and results in the requests being sent out sequentially rather simultaneously, possibly causing it to take longer to get all of the requested html (causing the previously mentioned lock to last longer).

Comment: Nobody should be using synchronous HTTP requests in 2021.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, using deferred objects.

```
var defArr = [];
defArr.push($.get('file.html'));
defArr.push($.get('pippo.html'));
$.when.apply($,defArr).done(function(response1,response2){
    $('.result').html(response1[2].responseText + response2[2].responseText);
});
```