# jquery multiple load html files with a callback

Tags: javascript

I've found a similar answer [jQuery load multiple html files in one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605673/jquery-load-multiple-html-files-in-one-element) but I'm looking a solution with a callback once everything's is loaded. It doesn't have to be jQuery, can be another js library.

```
$.get("file.htm", '', function (data) { $("#result").append(data); });
$.get("pippo.htm", '', function (data) { $("#result").append(data); });
```

Comment: This is a similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898813/jquery-wait-till-multiple-get-requests-are-successully-processed).

Comment: Do you mean once everything inside the file you are loading is loaded?